# Flutter :- Addition of new Widget to the Widget Tree, makes the other Widgets disappear

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey there I have been trying to add multiple widgets in a column widget in flutter, But everytime I add a second widget the first widget disappears as if the column widget crashed, I running it on my android phone using `vscode` the debug console shows no errors whatsoever. Im attaching the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:thejointapp/Appbar.dart';
import 'package:thejointapp/Grid.dart';
import 'package:thejointapp/SubjectSelector.dart';

void main() => runApp(Home());

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
   return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Home',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.red,
      accentColor: Color(0xFFFEF9EB),
    ),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: Appbar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SubjectSelector(),
          GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            children: List.generate(100, (index) {
              return (Center(
                  child: Text(
                'Item $index',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                // TextStyle(
                //     color: Colors.white,
                //     fontSize: 20.0,
                //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )));
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: What is the 'SubjectSelector' ?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha its another widget that i have seperated out, works just fine.

Comment: Ok ,let me try, will give you solution

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Sure!!

Comment: You want to scroll the whole screen or the specific portion of the Gridview?

Comment: Please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the **`Expand`** widget on the Gridview , like below

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Home',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.red,
          accentColor: Color(0xFFFEF9EB),
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  children: List.generate(100, (index) {
                    return (Center(
                        child: Text(
                      'Item $index',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                      // TextStyle(
                      //     color: Colors.white,
                      //     fontSize: 20.0,
                      //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )));
                  }),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And output will be following

[image]

And writing another answer for the full screen scroll with the `gridview` and ith other widgets. For it you need to use the `CustomScrollView` with `Silver` like below

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        // TODO: implement createState
        return HomeState();
      }
    }

    class HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Home',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: Colors.red,
              accentColor: Color(0xFFFEF9EB),
            ),
            home: Scaffold(
                appBar: new AppBar(),
                body: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: [
                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.2,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text("Top"),
                        ),
                      )
                    ),

                    SliverGrid(
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                      ),
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (context, index) => Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                        childCount: 10,

                      ),
                    ),

                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.2,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Bottom"),
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                )));
      }
    }
```

And output of the following program as follow

[image]

Comment: Definitely , You are a life saver, also could you please recommend good source to learn flutter?

Comment: I am also not an expertise in it..But you check this link for the reference https://flutter-widget.live/widgets/